# Rails 3 recursive polymorphic comments model, how to do redirect to top-most parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, recursion, polymorphic-associations

I'm still earning my stripes in Rails and have ran into a problem I can use some help on.  I'm building an app that has various models (stories, photos, artwork, etc.) that a user can comment on, as well as the comments themselves.  I have 98-99% of the functionality working but am stuck on getting the redirect to redirect to the top-most parent (a story, photo, etc.) after the comment has been created.

My comment model look like this:

```
# /app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

...I have several models that a user can comment on, for example a story model:

```
# /app/models/story.rb
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

My comments controller looks like this at this point:

```
# /app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  protected

  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
  end

end
```

...And of course my routes look like this:

```
# /config/routes.rb
resources :comments do
  resources :comments
end

resources :stories do
  resources :comments
end
```

The particular line I need to change is the `redirect_to :back` line (everything else, the polymorphism, the recursion of comments, etc. works fine).  The current code works as intended when a user is commenting on a story but it's not ideal when a user is commenting on a comment because the form for that functionality is not on the story "show" page (perhaps it needs to be?).

What I have tried to do (and what I suspect the solution might be) is a method that finds the parent object and recurses when that object is a comment.  My previous attempts at doing this has not been clean at all and I have yet to get a working prototype working.

I used this [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) to base the majority of my code but the `redirect_to :id => nil` doesn't work for me as the create comment method is somehow called and it results in a `NilClass error` when it attempts to build comments (perhaps something is wrong with my routing as I don't see how the index action would call create?).

So Rails experts, what am I doing wrong? What do I need to do here to get this working?  I feel like I'm 99% there but that last 1% is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

OK i had to read this a couple times...

```
@comment.commentable
```

would return an instance of Story or whatever object that did the comment.

Comment: For sure, this is definitely part of the solution.  I need to do this in recursion when a comment is nested under (potentially) a series of other comments.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this...It's probably not the cleanest but it works:

I first added a method in comments controller...

```
def get_master
  @parent = @comment.commentable
  if @parent.respond_to?('commentable_type')
    @comment = @parent
    get_master
  else
    return @parent
  end
end
```

Then I changed my redirect_to to call this method in the create controller.

The key was understanding that @object.respond_to? was what I needed to do check if a method is defined.

Here's a full example of how it works: http://t.co/N6WIGzuW